# How to authenticate user in gRPC

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

How, on Go gRPC server, inside a method handler get the user data, not utilizing https://go.dev/ref/spec metadata (not attaching tokens or anything like that to each call) but utilizing only a fact that connections are persistent and user may be authenticated at connect time?

I want scenario, looks very common and definetely possible with persistent TCP conn:

- user makes gRPC connection to a server, sending username and password
- grpc server validating him if credentials are invalid - disconnect
- remembers user login time
- user calls method GetMyLoginTime, its not allowed to pass any creds in request body or request metadata
- server responds with this user login time

How can achieve it with following Example setup:

proto def:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

service Test {
    rpc GetMyLoginTime(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Timestamp) {};
}
```

generates

```
type UnimplementedTestServer struct {
}

func (UnimplementedTestServer) GetMyLoginTime(context.Context, *emptypb.Empty) (*timestamppb.Timestamp, error) {
    return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unimplemented, "method GetMyLoginTime not implemented")
}
```

where to get associated underlying tcp connection? where to check user credentials and see if this connection even can be established on serverside?

Comment: With your current protos, somebody can call `GetMyLoginTime` without a session.  Why don't you want to include a session/auth token with the requests?

Comment: @StephenNewell thats what i want. asking - how to create a session, externally? when grpc client connects to grpc server, sending credentials, and server decides if to keep session or not allow client to connect.. and only then authenticated user can call a method

Comment: or, in other words, you are saying - each method needs to implement session mechanism, it cannot sit outside methods? what if i had 1000 methods, now i should modify each one to start accept authentication?) cant it be on a protocol level, since each connection is essentially a client session?

Comment: gRPC deliberately abstracts the concept of a connection. The client may connect multiple times for parallelism, disconnect if the connection remains idle for too long, reconnect to another server behind a load balancer, and so on.

Comment: @Thomas got it, so session can be done maximum on a grpc stream level, minimum?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build a session. This is because the server has no way of knowing who the client is if you don't pass any creds. Have you heard of GRPC interceptors? They are like HTTP middleware but for GRPC. You could use them to build a session.

The a look at this example.
https://dev.to/techschoolguru/use-grpc-interceptor-for-authorization-with-jwt-1c5h